# Call functions with special prefix/suffix

Tags: string, function, go

I have a package named "seeder":

```
package seeder

import "fmt"

func MyFunc1() {
    fmt.Println("I am Masood")
}

func MyFunc2() {
    fmt.Println("I am a programmer")
}

func MyFunc3() {
    fmt.Println("I want to buy a car")
}
```

Now I want to call all functions with MyFunc prefix

```
package main

import "./seeder"

func main() {
    for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
        seeder.MyFunc1() // This calls MyFunc1 three times
    }
}
```

I want something like this:

```
for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
    seeder.MyFunc + k ()
}
```

and this output:

> ```
> I am Masood
> I am a programmer
> I want to buy a car
> ```

**EDIT1**:
In this example, parentKey is a string variable which changed in a loop

```
for parentKey, _ := range uRLSjson{ 
    pppp := seeder + "." + strings.ToUpper(parentKey)
    gorilla.HandleFunc("/", pppp).Name(parentKey)
}
```

But GC said:

> use of package seeder without selector

Comment: Hi Masood. In your sub functions don't you mean to say the Hello World text matches the function not all MyFunc1?: i.e.  func MyFunc2() {
    fmt.Println("Hello MyFunc2")
}

Comment: Ok great I see you have fixed this.

Comment: Hi no I mean call funcs with special prefix. Lets change fmt output  to be more than clear

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't get a function by its name, and that is what you're trying to do. The reason is that if the Go tool can detect that a function is not referred to explicitly (and thus unreachable), it may not even get compiled into the executable binary. For details see [Splitting client/server code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875016/splitting-client-server-code/38875901#38875901).

#### With a function registry

One way to do what you want is to build a "function registry" prior to calling them:

```
registry := map[string]func(){
    "MyFunc1": MyFunc1,
    "MyFunc2": MyFunc2,
    "MyFunc3": MyFunc3,
}
for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
    registry[fmt.Sprintf("MyFunc%d", k)]()
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SePjpsDkyT)):

```
Hello MyFunc1
Hello MyFunc2
Hello MyFunc3
```

#### Manual "routing"

Similar to the registry is inspecting the name and manually routing to the function, for example:

```
func callByName(name string) {
    switch name {
    case "MyFunc1":
        MyFunc1()
    case "MyFunc2":
        MyFunc2()
    case "MyFunc3":
        MyFunc3()
    default:
        panic("Unknown function name")
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
    callByName(fmt.Sprintf("MyFunc%d", k))
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j3DqtPbNrv).

**Note:** It's up to you if you want to call the function identified by its name in the `callByName()` helper function, or you may choose to return a function value (of type `func()`) and have it called in the caller's place.

#### Transforming functions to methods

Also note that if your functions would actually be *methods* of some type, you could do it without a registry. Using reflection, you can get a method by name: [`Value.MethodByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName). You can also get / enumerate all methods without knowing their names using [`Value.NumMethod()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.NumMethod) and [`Value.Method()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Method) (also see `Type.NumMethod()` and `Type.Method()` if you need the name of the method or its parameter types).

This is how it could be done:

```
type MyType int

func (m MyType) MyFunc1() {
    fmt.Println("Hello MyFunc1")
}

func (m MyType) MyFunc2() {
    fmt.Println("Hello MyFunc2")
}

func (m MyType) MyFunc3() {
    fmt.Println("Hello MyFunc3")
}

func main() {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(MyType(0))
    for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
        v.MethodByName(fmt.Sprintf("MyFunc%d", k)).Call(nil)
    }
}
```

Output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/v7Jgo_D-Ik).

Comment: Thank but is there any other way without map?

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh You may do it with a registry, or by transforming functions to methods. Having functions and no registry - you can't.

Comment: or `reflect`, which helping turn string to function.

Comment: @JiangYD You can't get a function by name using `reflect`, only methods.

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh Considering your edit to the question, the answers still stand: you can't do it without a registry or using methods instead of functions.

Comment: Thanks I just change MyType type to string It's working.

Comment: yes I missed it. why golang designed  not get to `Package` at runtime?

Comment: Sorry It's not working because in my example functions write by user and I'm going to connect those functions with special prefix or suffix like "route" to gorilla.

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh As said previously, if they remain functions (and you can't make them methods), you can only do it with a function registry (or some other construct, explicitly listing the names, routing them to functions manually).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to range over an array of your functions

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func MyFunc1() {
    fmt.Println("I am Masood")
}

func MyFunc2() {
    fmt.Println("I am a programmer")
}

func MyFunc3() {
    fmt.Println("I want to buy a car")
}


func main() {
   for _, fn := range []func(){MyFunc1, MyFunc2, MyFunc3} {
        fn()
    }
}
```