# go files organisation for two apps with shared code

Tags: go

I have a client and server application that share some code. I would like to group them all in a single directory under git control.

In this directory I can create two sub-directories, one for the client and one for the server. The compiled code will have the name of the directory provided I compile them using `go install` from within their respective directory.

What is unclear is how to deal with the shared code (.go files) which I don't want to copy in each repository.

Am I required to create a separate package ? Can this package be stored in the common root directory ?

**EDIT 1**: Here is an example to make the question clear

The directory *thing* is for the project. It contains the *thingClient* and *thingServer* directory containing the client and server specific go files.

The client and server use common functions stored in specific files. I want these common files to be stored in .../go/src/thing so that they remain in the same git repository. I don't want them to be compiled into a shared library.

`.../go/src/thing  <-- under git control
.../go/src/thing/thingClient   <-- contains main.go of client
.../go/src/thing/thingServer   <-- contains main.go of server
.../go/src/thing/ ???          <-- contains go files used by client and server`

I would prefer avoiding to create a package containing those common files if possible.

**EDIT 2**: According to this documentation [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) I do have to create a package containing the shared code and import it in the client and server code. The package would be stored in a specific directory named for instance `.../go/src/thing/common`. All go files inside common should declare to be member of the package named *common*. The client and server source files should then `import thing/common` to access the shared source code.

Another important point is the project directory. To avoid package name collisions, the project directory should be renamed using a URL like path with a unique domain name, e.g. "github/user/thing". This will avoid any collision. The project source files should then be stored under `.../go/src/github/user/thing/...`. The client and server should then import "github/user/thing/common".

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Splitting client/server code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875016/splitting-client-server-code)

Comment: And don't forget about the workaround for [this](https://golang.org/issue/15093)

Comment: @icza It's not a duplicate in that I'm not concerned by dead code removal. ? I'll give an example to make my question more clear.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but what's the problem with importing from a shared package ?

Comment: @Sridhar I thought that creating a package would require me to create a directory outside of the project directory `thing`. See my Edit2. I now understood how it must be done. If you provide this info as answer I'll validate it. I can't answer myself yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create a directory called util under thing and have all files in util as package util. You should then be able to import thing/util from your client & server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this, [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) create a package containing the shared code and import it in the client and server code.

The package can be stored in a specific directory named for instance .../go/src/thing/common. All go files inside common should declare to be a member of the package named common. The client and server source files should then import thing/common to access the shared source code.

To avoid package name collisions, the project directory can be renamed using a URL like path with a unique domain name, e.g. "github.com/user/thing". This will avoid any collision. The project source files can then be stored under .../go/src/github.com/user/thing/....

The client and server can then import "github.com/user/thing/common".

If there are no source files directly under github.com/user/thing you can create a new empty file with just a package name in it to get around [this](https://golang.org/issue/15093) until 1.8