# How to get Type representation from name via reflection?

Tags: go, reflection, types, go-reflect

Is there a way to use the [reflection libraries](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) in Go to go from the name of a type to its [Type](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) representation?

I've got a library where the user needs to provide Type representations for some code generation. I know it must be possible (in a sense) because  they can just create a variable of that type and call the [TypeOf function](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), but is there a way to circumvent this and just get representation from the name?

Comment: The reflect package does not contain this functionality.  If you are generating code, then the [go/types](https://godoc.org/go/types) or [go/ast](https://godoc.org/go/ast) packages may be of use.

Comment: No. Use a registry of names -> types association for lookup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is not quite explicit, it can be interpreted in 2 ways, to one of which the answer is no, not possible; and the other to which the answer is yes, it's possible.

#### At runtime

If the type name is provided as a `string` value, then at runtime it's not possible as types that are not referred to explicitly may not get compiled into the final executable binary (and thus obviously become unreachable, "unknown" at runtime). For details see  [Splitting client/server code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875016/splitting-client-server-code/38875901#38875901). For possible workarounds see [Call all functions with special prefix or suffix in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-all-functions-with-special-prefix-or-suffix-in-golang/37384665#37384665).

#### At "coding" time

If we're talking about "coding" time (source code writing / generating), then it's possible without creating / allocating a variable of the given type and calling [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) and passing the variable.

You may start from the *pointer* to the type, and use a *typed `nil`* pointer value without allocation, and you can navigate from its [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptor to the descriptor of the *base* type (or *element* type) of the pointer using `Type.Elem()`.

This is how it looks like:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*YourType)(nil)).Elem()
```

The type descriptor `t` above will be identical to `t2` below:

```
var x YourType
t2 := reflect.TypeOf(x)

fmt.Println(t, t2)
fmt.Println(t == t2)
```

Output of the above application (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W_6MMkxoAS)):

```
main.YourType main.YourType
true
```