# How to get the string representation of a type?

Tags: go, reflection, types

Let's say I have the following type defined:

```
type ID uuid.UUID
```

How would I get the type as string in a programmatic way so it's easy to refactor later other than maybe:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%T", ID{})
```

which I don't quite like because it instantiates it, also from an Interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) (the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package does that too under the hood). You may start from the *pointer* to the type, and use a *typed `nil`* pointer value without allocation, and you can navigate from its [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptor to the descriptor of the *base* type (or *element* type) of the pointer using `Type.Elem()`.

Example:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*ID)(nil)).Elem()
name := t.Name()
fmt.Println(name)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9tWT6xGweW)):

```
ID
```

Note: be aware that `Type.Name()` may return an empty `string` (if the `Type` represents an unnamed type). If you're using a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) (with the `type` keyword), then you already named the type, so `Type.Name()` will return a non-empty type name. But using the above code for a variable of type `*[]string` for example will give you an empty string:

```
var s *[]string
t := reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()
name := t.Name()
fmt.Printf("%q", name)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jgsuo60XQm)):

```
""
```

See related questions:

[Golang reflect: Get Type representation from name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879748/golang-reflect-get-type-representation-from-name/40882963#40882963)

[Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523)