# Save Type for latter reflection

Tags: go, types, casting

I'm trying to do something like this:

Struct to save setting:

```
type Setting struct{
    Name            string
    DataType        types.Type
}
```

Setting definition:

```
var SETTING_DebugLogging Setting = Setting{
    Name: "DebugLogging",
    DataType: bool,    <-- This is wrong
}
```

and then, get the value from a Map using reflection and the value on DataType:

```
// Get a value setting, or his default
func (s Setting) Get() interface{}{
    val, ok := settings[s].(s.DataType)    <-- This is wrong
    if !ok{
        return s.DefaultValue.(s.DataType)   <-- This is wrong
    }

    return val
}
```

I wan't to do this way, to ensure "Get" is always returning the value expected for that setting. If it's an invalid one, returns the default value, so I don't have to check again in code.

Just doing var := setting.Get().(setting.DataType) would be enough, no checks needed.

I've also tried to use reflection.kind to save the type of the setting. And that works for storing it, but I can't use it to parse latter:

This is ok with reflect.Kind:

```
// Game to launch
var SETTING_GameToLaunch Setting = Setting{
    Name: "GameToLaunch",
    DataType: reflect.Bool,
    DefaultValue: 2,
}
```

But this doesn't work latter:

```
func (s Setting) Get() interface{}{
    val, ok := settings[s].(s.DataType)
```

So. Any ideas on how I can do that?
Store a type, and use latter with reflection?

Comment: I would strongly advise against this design if you can possibly avoid it. This is more like Java code than Go code and will lead to further frustration as implementation continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use / store [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type). In `Get()`, you may check if the value is of that type, e.g. `reflect.TypeOf(settings[s]) == s.DataType`.

But it would be simpler to just use a struct, and enumerate settings as fields. That will be type safe, and you don't have to use type assertions when using / getting setting values.

Comment: reflect.Type doesn't work either. I can't store that. Comparission works, but I can't save a reflect.type value. And yes. That's the way I did for other settings in my app, but In this ones, I need to have diferent permissions. (Read/Write). I simplified the struct, but there are more things there, so this is the best approach I've found. The problem is that I don't know how to store/assign a type

Comment: @FacundoCurti _"I don't know how to store/assign a type"_ Which part is you don't know? You may create `reflect.Type` using `reflect.TypeOf()`, e.g. `reflect.TypeOf(false)` to have the type descriptor for `bool`.

Comment: Ohh. Lol. That's how. Thx a lot :D I guess there is no way to create a Type, without using reflect.TypeOf()? Something like var := Type(string). I've got enforced to use even casting in some cases: DataType: reflect.TypeOf(uint32(0))

Comment: @FacundoCurti Yes, you need a value, you can't write`reflect.TypeOf(bool)`. Also as you wrote, if you need a type other than the default type of an untyped constant, you need explicit type conversion, such as `reflect.TypeOf(uint32(0))`. Also see: [Golang TypeOf without an instance and passing result to a func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939416/golang-typeof-without-an-instance-and-passing-result-to-a-func/48944430#48944430)