# How to check that a return value of a function satisfies the error interface

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

I'd like to write some code which inspects the methods of a struct and makes certain assertions on them, for example, that the last thing returned by them should be an `error`. I've tried the following example script:

```
import (
    "context"
    "reflect"
)

type Service struct {
    name string
}

func (svc *Service) Handle(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    return svc.name, nil
}

func main() {
    s := &Service{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        f := t.Method(i).Func.Type()

        f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1).Implements(reflect.TypeOf(error))
    }
}
```

However, this yields a

```
./main.go:23:51: type error is not an expression
```

What does compile are instead the following two lines at the end:

```
    var err error
    f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1).Implements(reflect.TypeOf(err))
```

However, this yields a panic:

```
panic: reflect: nil type passed to Type.Implements
```

What would be the correct way to check that the last arguments implements the `error` interface? In other words, how do I get a `reflect.Type` of an `error` interface?

Comment: You probably want to determine if the last result has type `error`, not that it implements `error`.  If so, use  `f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1) == reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Golang TypeOf without an instance and passing result to a func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939416/golang-typeof-without-an-instance-and-passing-result-to-a-func/48944430#48944430).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pointer to interface, and get the `Elem` of it, like this:

```
f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1).Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem())
```

Answer (score 4):

If the last return value *"should be"* and `error` do not use `Implements`, that's not sufficient, x *implements* e is not the same as x *is* e.

Just check the type's name and package path. For predeclared types, including `error`, the package path is an empty string.

---

A non-error type that implements `error`.

```
type Service struct {
    name string
}

type sometype struct {}

func (sometype) Error() string { return "" }

func (svc *Service) Handle(ctx context.Context) (string, sometype) {
    return svc.name, sometype{}
}

func main() {
    s := &Service{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        f := t.Method(i).Func.Type()
        rt := f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1)
        fmt.Printf("implements error? %t\n", rt.Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()))
        fmt.Printf("is error? %t\n", rt.Name() == "error" && rt.PkgPath() == "")
    }
}
```

This [outputs](https://play.golang.com/p/aU_rt35-E9f):

```
implements error? true
is error? false
```

---

A locally declared type named `error` that doesn't implement the builtin `error`.

```
type Service struct {
    name string
}

type error interface { Abc() }

func (svc *Service) Handle(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    return svc.name, nil
}

type builtin_error interface { Error() string }

func main() {
    s := &Service{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        f := t.Method(i).Func.Type()
        rt := f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1)
        fmt.Printf("implements error? %t\n", rt.Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*builtin_error)(nil)).Elem()))
        fmt.Printf("is error? %t\n", rt.Name() == "error" && rt.PkgPath() == "")
    }
}
```

This [outputs](https://play.golang.com/p/Y4Lh5uE48Lo):

```
implements error? false
is error? false
```

---

The actual builtin `error`.

```
type Service struct {
    name string
}

func (svc *Service) Handle(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    return svc.name, nil
}

func main() {
    s := &Service{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        f := t.Method(i).Func.Type()
        rt := f.Out(f.NumOut() - 1)
        fmt.Printf("implements error? %t\n", rt.Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()))
        fmt.Printf("is error? %t\n", rt.Name() == "error" && rt.PkgPath() == "")
    }
}
```

This [outputs](https://play.golang.com/p/nJrpqhCeuZ1):

```
implements error? true
is error? true
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the `reflect.TypeOf` of an `error` without using an existing error, you can use this one-liner:

```
reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()
```

Basically, it first gets type of a pointer to error (`*error`) and then `Elem()` "deferences" the TypeOf to the type of `error`.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M7t4GFgFe1w)