# Print a type without using reflrect and create new object

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection, types

In below code, in order to show the expected type, I have to create a new object and call `reflect.TypeOf` on it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type X struct {
    name string
}

func check(something interface{}) {
    if _, ok := something.(*X); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Expecting type %v, got %v\n", 
            reflect.TypeOf(X{}), reflect.TypeOf(something))
    }
}

func main() 
    check(struct{}{})
}
```

Perhaps that object creation is not an overhead, but I still curious to know a better way. Are there something like `X.getName()` or `X.getSimpleName()` in java?

Comment: Use `reflect.TypeOf((*X)(nil)).Elem()` to avoid having to create a value of `X`. For printing the type of a value, you may use `fmt.Printf("%T", something)`.

Comment: Thank for `%T`. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptor of a type, you may use

```
reflect.TypeOf((*X)(nil)).Elem()
```

to avoid having to create a value of type `X`. See these questions for more details:

[How to get the string representation of a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905222/how-to-get-the-string-representation-of-a-type/41905585#41905585)

[Golang TypeOf without an instance and passing result to a func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939416/golang-typeof-without-an-instance-and-passing-result-to-a-func/48944430#48944430)

And to print the type of some value, you may use `fmt.Printf("%T, something)`.

And actually for what you want to do, you may put reflection aside completely, simply do:

```
fmt.Printf("Expecting type %T, got %T\n", (*X)(nil), something)
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mjVKMRa71l7)):

```
Expecting type *main.X, got struct {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflects is almost always a bad choice. You can consider using one of the following ways

## Use switch

If you want to control the flow depending on the type you can use the `switch` construction

```
func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v*2)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v))
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }
}
```

## Use `fmt` package

If you want only to display its type you can always use the `fmt` package

```
i := 1000
fmt.Printf("The type is %T", i)
```

Comment: _"Using reflects is almost always a bad choice."_ I disagree with this. The `fmt` package also uses reflection to achieve the same.

Comment: yes but this scenario you use it not directly. -> http://www.jerf.org/iri/post/2945. From the official blog you can find "Once you understand these laws reflection in Go becomes much easier to use, although it remains subtle. It's a powerful tool that should be used with care and avoided unless strictly necessary."