# Package selector with string name

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to figure out a way to access struct from multiple packages with name.

Here is my structure:

```
collector/package1
collector/package2
```

..
package1 contains:

```
package collector

type NewRule struct {
}
```

..
package2 contains:

```
package collector

type OldRule struct {
}
```

....

In my main.go:

```
 import "github.com/mypackage/collector"

 sliceOfCollector := []string{"NewRule", "OldRule"}

 for _, col := range sliceOfCollector{
      // How to use the above collector name `col` to create struct instance.
 }
```

Comment: Related: [Call all functions with special prefix or suffix in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-all-functions-with-special-prefix-or-suffix-in-golang/37384665#37384665).

Comment: Thank you @icza, that is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reflect.New](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) with `struct` type. In Go you have to use type to create a new instance dynamically not string.

Example: To create struct instance dynamically, you can do

```
package main

import "reflect"

import (
   "github.com/collector/package1"
   "github.com/collector/package2"
)

func main() {
    sliceOfCollector := make([]reflect.Type, 0)
    sliceOfCollector = append(sliceOfCollector, reflect.TypeOf((*package1.NewRule)(nil)).Elem()})
    sliceOfCollector = append(sliceOfCollector, reflect.TypeOf((*package2.OldRule)(nil)).Elem()})

    for _, collectorType := range slice sliceOfCollector {
        col := reflect.New(collectorType)
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", col)
    }
}
```

You can use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) after that `col.Interface().(*package1.NewRule)`

---

**EDIT:**

After comment interaction, added following.

Creating a instance using factory method. Just an idea.

```
func main() {
    sliceOfCollector := []string{"NewRule", "OldRule"}

    for _, col := range sliceOfCollector {
        rule := CreateRuleByName(col)
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", rule)
    }
}

func CreateRuleByName(name string) interface{} {
    switch name {
    case "NewRule":
       return &package1.NewRule{}
    case "OldRule":
       return &package2.OldRule{}
    default:
       return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my sliceOfCollector is slice of string name. Is there any way to do from name?

Comment: It is not possible to create from string name, you need a `type`.  Otherwise as an alternative, you may have to follow factory pattern sort of; supply string to function and have `switch/if` then create a instance normally `package1.NewRule{}` then return it.

Comment: Okk. let me try

Comment: Shall I add the example of that in the answer? let me know.