# How to add function to cron using Go reflect?

Tags: go, cron

I am trying to schedule few jobs dynamically by reading configuration from file like below

```
import (
   "github.com/robfig/cron" 
   "fmt"
)
    masterJobDetails :=// this is array of job from file

    c := cron.New()
        for k, v := range masterJobDetails {

            fmt.Println(k, v.JobName)
            c.AddFunc(v.CronExpression, v.JobName)//JobName is function name in string format which need to call on specific interval

        }

        c.Start()
```

c.AddFunc() expect cron expression and func() as input,Can i get second argument using reflect with  v.JobName string value

Comment: You can't refer to functions given by their names. Possible duplicate of [Call all functions with special prefix or suffix in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-all-functions-with-special-prefix-or-suffix-in-golang/37384665#37384665).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot cast `string` to `func()` type. Instead use `switch` or `map` to find the actual function.

```
for k, v := range masterJobDetails {
    var jobFunc func()
    switch v.JobName {
    case "job1":
        jobFunc = job1
    case "job2":
        jobFunc = job2      

    }
    c.AddFunc(v.CronExpression, jobFunc)
}
```